# Call Fragment as an Activity in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I have this method that requires activity, but I want to use it with a fragment but it gives me an error "Incompatible type"

```
fun loadUserData(activity: Activity) {
    mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS).document(getCurrentUserID()).get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            Log.e(activity.javaClass.simpleName, document.toString())

            val loggedInUser = document.toObject(User::class.java)!!

            when (activity) {
                is LogIn -> {
                    activity.signInSuccess(loggedInUser)
                }
                is  NavigationHomePage->{
                    activity.updateHomeUserHomeScreen(loggedInUser)
                }
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Log.e(
                activity.javaClass.simpleName,
                "Error while getting loggedIn user details", e
            )
        }
}
```

the **NavigationHomePage** is the fragment.. so how to do this exactly

Answer (score 0):

Use **requireActivity()**.

```
fun loadUserData() {
    mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS).document(getCurrentUserID()).get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            Log.e(requireActivity().javaClass.simpleName, document.toString())

            val loggedInUser = document.toObject(User::class.java)!!

            when (requireActivity()) {
                is LogIn -> {
                    requireActivity().signInSuccess(loggedInUser)
                }
                is  NavigationHomePage->{
                    requireActivity().updateHomeUserHomeScreen(loggedInUser)
                }
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Log.e(
                requireActivity().javaClass.simpleName,
                "Error while getting loggedIn user details", e
            )
        }
}
```

Comment: requireActivity() didn't work, it doesn't recognize it...

Comment: the method loadUserData is in a base class the I use for all firebase functions

Comment: From where are you calling the function? Fragment or Activity?

Comment: I'm calling it from activities and fragments and it doesn't give any errors from there, but because the function itself requires passing an activity so it gives an error in the base class that is in...so how can I pass a fragment to the function instead of activity without having an error